# Running my activity on wake like default pattern lock

Tags: java, android

I have a custom lock kind of like the default pattern lock I want to have launch like the default pattern lock, after I slide to unlock in widgetlocker. It also has to block the home and back keys. What's the easiest way to do this?

Edited:

Sorry, it's an Archos 43. I'm running UrukDroid 1.0 which is open-source. Uruk is based on the stock Archos firmware (Android 2.2.1). The Archos firmware is open-source too, I just can't find a good example of how to do this.

Comment: What have you already done? You should show some effort rather then ask for "CodeZZ"

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the signing key for the system firmware (or you have a custom rom that removes some security features), it's not possible to do what you're looking to do. Specifically, you cannot block the home key.